# No matching constructor for initialization of variadic template class

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, stdtuple

I am trying to write a wrapper class to a Cartesian product iterator provided by Miranda Conrado (source code can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/mirandaconrado/product-iterator)). For convenience I will quote relevant bits of code here, too.

My class can be constructed in two ways - one straightforward, by just forwarding the Containers to the `product_iterator` constructor, the other is a bit trickier: it takes a number of tuples describing the linspace needed to create the Containers and then constructs the iterator out of them. It is here where I hit a dead-end.

Here is some code.
First, some relevant headers from Conrado's `class product_iterator`:

```cpp
// product_iterator.hpp

template <class... Containers>
class product_iterator:
    ...

    public:
      product_iterator();

      product_iterator(product_iterator const& other);

      product_iterator(Containers const&... containers);

      ~product_iterator();

      product_iterator const& operator=(product_iterator const& other);

     ....
};

template <class... Containers>
product_iterator<Containers...>
make_product_iterator(Containers const&... containers) {
  return product_iterator<Containers...>(containers...);
}
```

And here is my class:

```cpp
// gridsearch.hpp

typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, Real> result_type;
typedef std::vector<result_type> resultgrid_type;


template <class... Containers>
class GridSearchIterator {
    typedef std::array<std::string,
            std::tuple_size<std::tuple<Containers...> >::value> 
            argname_type;

public:
    GridSearchIterator() : product_it(product_iterator<Containers...>()), 
                           argnames(argname_type()) {}

    GridSearchIterator(const argname_type& names, 
                       const Containers& ...containers);

    template <class... TupleTypes>
    static GridSearchIterator<Containers...> 
                                    initWith(const TupleTypes&& ...tuples);

    template<class F, class... Args>
    decltype(auto) iterate(F func, Args&&... params);

private:
    template <typename TupleType, size_t... Is>
    void product_impl(TupleType&& tuples, std::index_sequence<Is...>);
    template <typename TupleType>
    const auto& unpack_tuple(TupleType& t, size_t index);

    product_iterator<Containers...> product_it;
    argname_type argnames;
};

// implementation:

template <class... Containers>
GridSearchIterator<Containers...>::GridSearchIterator(
                                          const argname_type& names, 
                                          const Containers& ...containers):

                product_it(product_iterator<Containers...>(containers...)),
                                                        argnames(names) {}

template <class... Containers>
template <typename... TupleTypes>
GridSearchIterator<Containers...> GridSearchIterator<Containers...>::initWith(const TupleTypes&& ...tuples) 
{
    GridSearchIterator<Containers...> gsi = 
                                       GridSearchIterator<Containers...>();
    gsi.product_impl(std::tuple<TupleTypes...>(tuples...), 
                     std::index_sequence_for<TupleTypes...>{});
    return gsi;
}

template <class... Containers>
template <typename TupleType, size_t... Is>
void GridSearchIterator<Containers...>::product_impl(TupleType&& tuples, 
                                              std::index_sequence<Is...>) 
{
    product_it = product_iterator<Containers...>(
                                unpack_tuple(std::get<Is>(tuples), Is)...); 
// this is where the problem is; Compiler claims No matching constructor for initialization of 'product_iterator...
}

template <class... Containers>
template <typename TupleType>
const auto& GridSearchIterator<Containers...>::unpack_tuple(TupleType &t, 
                                                            size_t index) 
{
    std::string argname;
    auto left(0), right(0);
    Size step;
    std::tie(argname, left, right, step) = t;
    argnames[index] = argname;
    auto vec = linspace(left, right, step);
    return static_cast<const decltype(vec) &>(vec);
}
```

The function `linspace` above returns a vector of numbers from `left` to `right` evenly spaced by number of `step`s. It is equivalent to Numpy function `np.linspace`.

I checked and the call to `unpack_tuple()` does produce the vectors needed to initialise the `product_iterator`, yet the compiler disagrees. My guess is the types returned by `unpack_tuple()` are somewhat different from what the `product_iterator` constructor expects but I can't figure out what is the problem. Or maybe the problem actually lies elsewhere entirely.

For better understanding, here is how I use the class:

```cpp
{
...
    typedef std::tuple<std::string, int, int, size_t> inttuple;
    typedef std::tuple<std::string, double, double, size_t> realtuple;
    typedef std::vector<int> intvector;
    typedef std::vector<Real> realvector;

    inttuple sidespan = std::make_tuple("side",1,1,1);
    real tuple takeprofit = std::make_tuple("takeprofit",1.,2.,2);
    real tuple stoploss = std::make_tuple("stoploss", -1.,-3.,3);
    inttuple period = std::make_tuple("horizon", 100, 100, 1);

    auto grid_iter = GridSearchIterator<intvector, realvector, realvector, intvector>
                                        ::initWith(std::forward<inttuple>(sidespan),
                                                   std::forward<realtuple>(takeprofit),
                                                   std::forward<realtuple>(stoploss),
                                                   std::forward<inttuple>(period));
...
}
```

I spent hours trying to solve it so any help or pointers will be highly appreciated, including advice on different implementation.

**UPDATE**
Sorry, I thought I updated my question yesterday but the changes were not saved for some reason. 
Anyway, @max66 answered the question even without additional info. Still, for completeness, here is the `linspace()` definition

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> linspace(T a, T b, size_t N)
```

and compiler message:

> In file included from /.../main.cpp:17:
>   /.../gridsearch.hpp:98:18: error: no matching constructor for initialization of `'product_iterator<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >, std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > >'
>       product_it = product_iterator<Containers...>(unpack_tuple(std::get<Is>(tuples), Is)...);`
>
> /.../gridsearch.hpp:91:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization `'GridSearchIterator<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >, std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > >::product_impl<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::basic_string<char>, int, int, unsigned long>, std::__1::tuple<std::__1::basic_string<char>, double, double, unsigned long>, std::__1::tuple<std::__1::basic_string<char>, double, double, unsigned long>, std::__1::tuple<std::__1::basic_string<char>, int, int, unsigned long> >, 0, 1, 2, 3>'` requested here `gsi.product_impl(std::tuple<TupleTypes...>(tuples...), std::index_sequence_for<TupleTypes...>{});`
>
> /.../main.cpp:90:88: note: in instantiation of function template specialization `'GridSearchIterator<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >, std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > >::initWith<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::basic_string<char>, int, int, unsigned long>, std::__1::tuple<std::__1::basic_string<char>, double, double, unsigned long>, std::__1::tuple<std::__1::basic_string<char>, double, double, unsigned long>, std::__1::tuple<std::__1::basic_string<char>, int, int, unsigned long> >'` requested here `auto grid_iter = GridSearchIterator<intvector, realvector, realvector, intvector>::initWith(std::forward<inttuple>(sidespan),`
>
> In file included from /.../main.cpp:17:
>   In file included from /.../gridsearch.hpp:22:
>   /.../product_iterator.hpp:73:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from `'vector<int, allocator<int>>' to 'const vector<double, allocator<double>>'` for 2nd argument `product_iterator(Containers const&... containers);`

Comment: _"yet the compiler disagrees"_ -- that's vague and incorporates interpretation/assumptions on your part. Which makes the statement largely useless for debugging help. What is the exact message from the compiler?

Comment: Please provide the linspace function prototype and full compiler error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to check/verify/propose a correct code if you don't propose a complete example.

Anyway you have the error ("no matching constructor") in this line

```
    product_it = product_iterator<Containers...>(
                                unpack_tuple(std::get<Is>(tuples), Is)...);
```

where, if I understand correctly, `Containers...` is `intvector, realvector, realvector, intvector` a.k.a. `std::vector<int>, std::vector<Real>, std::vector<Real>, std::vector<int>` (where I suppose `Real` is an alias for `double`).

The only variadic constructor for `product_iterator` is the one receiving `Containers const&... containers` so I suppose is the one you want to match.

It seems to me that the problem is that `unpack_tuple()`

```
template <class... Containers>
template <typename TupleType>
const auto& GridSearchIterator<Containers...>::unpack_tuple(TupleType &t, 
                                                            size_t index) 
{
    std::string argname;
    auto left(0), right(0);
    Size step;
    std::tie(argname, left, right, step) = t;
    argnames[index] = argname;
    auto vec = linspace(left, right, step);
    return static_cast<const decltype(vec) &>(vec);
}
```

return **ever** a `intVector const &` (`std::vector<int> const &`). Also when called with a `realVector` (`std::vector<double>`, I suppose).

This (if I'm not wrong) it's because you define `left` and `right` as `auto` and initializing they whit an `int`

```
auto left(0), right(0);
```

you get a couple of `int` also when `TupleType` contains `Real` elements in second and third position.

So when you obtain `vec`

```
auto vec = linspace(left, right, step);
```

you obtain (I suppose) a `std::vector<int>`; ever; also when you should obtain a `std::vector<Real>`.

Suggestion: define `left` and `right` with the correct type that depends from `TupleType`.

By example (caution: code not tested)

```
using lr_type = typename std::tuple_element<1u, TupleType>::type;

lr_type  left, right;
```

Starting from C++14 you can use `std::tuple_element_t` and the `using can be simplified as follows

```
using lr_type = std::tuple_element_t<1u, TupleType>;
```

If you can use C++17, you can use structured binding and all become a lot simpler

```
template <typename TupleType>
const auto& GridSearchIterator<Containers...>::unpack_tuple(TupleType &t, 
                                                            size_t index) 
{
    auto [argname, left, right, step] = t;
    argnames[index] = argname;
    auto vec = linspace(left, right, step);
    return static_cast<const decltype(vec) &>(vec);
}
```

Off Topic: are you sure that is a good idea `unpack_tuple()` returning a const **reference** to a value that is destroyed at the end of execution of the method ?

Comment: @max66Yes, that was exactly the reason it didn't compile. After your suggested changes it all works now. Thanks a lot! 
Regarding your last comment: it is actually an artefact of my desperate attempts to solve the problem. My initial implementation was just to return an rvalue, which is what I am going to use.